# How to conditionally render a component that uses hooks, i get error that component that uses hooks cannot do conditionallly render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component where if its loading state is true it returns a loading markup, if id false it returns something else.

But i get the error:

`React Hook is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.`

whats the correct way to fix this?

My component:

````
  const store = React.useContext(StoreContext);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  if(loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }
  return useObserver(() => (
    <div className="pa2">
      <div className="flex">
        {store.restaurantResults[store.selectedFood] &&
          store.restaurantResults[store.selectedFood].map((rest, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={i} className="pa2">
                <img src={rest.image_url} alt="restuarant" />
                <p>Reviews{rest.review_count}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
};```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `useObserver()` is a hook, you have to call it in every render, you can´t skip it conditionally.

One option would be to move the condition inside the hook callback, if that´s an option for you:

```
  return useObserver(() => (
    loading 
      ? <p>Loading...</p>
      : <div className="pa2">
          <div className="flex">
            {store.restaurantResults[store.selectedFood] &&
             store.restaurantResults[store.selectedFood].map((rest, i) => {
               return (
                 <div key={i} className="pa2">
                   <img src={rest.image_url} alt="restuarant" />
                   <p>Reviews{rest.review_count}</p>
                 </div>
               );
             })}
          </div>
        </div>
  );
};
```